# Not all tags are available in a Contact Search

Tags: search, tags

I have created a tag set which has one tag, "Changed Address". This tag is set using a rule when a contact's address is changed. When I perform a contact search, this tag does not show in the list of available tags.

Comment: I see that by doing an advanced search, I can select the rule that adds this tag. This is a bit obscure. I'd just like to search directly on the tag

Comment: Likewise, I'd like to be able to remove this tag with an action but the tag is not listed.

Comment: Did you make the tag applicable to contacts?

Comment: The contacts have this tag. I can't see the tag in the search list

Comment: Can you please look at Contacts/Manage Tags and click on the tag 'Changed Address' and see what is in 'Used For' and report back?

Comment: This tag is in a set called "Rules". The Rules set is used for Contacts. There is no "Used For" specified for the "Changed Address" tag in this set.

Comment: Okay. What do I do?

Comment: You could report this as an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues

Comment: In fact I finally managed to reproduce the problem, and it looks like a bug to me. I created a tag tree for contacts, and then added a tag for contacts - which appears against the contact but is then missing in search.  So maybe don't use a 'Tag Tree' for now.  Also, I couldn't see the tag that I created in 'Advanced Search' as you did.

Comment: I'll raise an issue